# How long should it take to Flash a image?

Tags: raspbian

How long should it take to Flash a image?it took 50 minutes to do it on the PI Imager,then when it had finished it falled.I tried it on Echer it took over 3 hours ?the same thing happend. But i got it on a USB FLASH DRIVE it took no time at all.Of course you can,t use a USB  drive or SSD until you update the firmware.I am doing it on echer it has been going for 35 minutes and only done 32%? i  on a 2017 5k Mac.I can,t see it working this time either.Why can,t the PI be able to be used with a SSD drive out of the box?

Comment: Have you tried with a different SD card or SD card adapter?

Comment: Even on a 2012 Mac mini it has never taken me more than 10 minutes to flash and verify any Pi image.  I use decent cards of 16Gb - normally SanDisk or Samsung A1 class.  Gut feel is you have a dying or fake SD card.

Comment: You are probberly right there  fake cards that is i did get them off ebay.they are Sandisk.It has been going for 25 minures now and only 26%/It did a USB in less than ten minutes.They are both new. There 32gb.Is that what they do if they are fake cards takes ages to do stuff?Usb adapter and the one for the SD slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never longer than 15 minutes. 50 minutes it's obvious that something went wrong. Probably your sd card is dying. Even if you flash an image onto that card the raspberry will be painfully slow.

Comment: Thanks for that Morgan.There was two fake cards from Ebay i have had them for some time so can,t get a refund.I flashed it on a card i used with the PI 3.Like you say took about ten minutes.Hope you are having a doos day.

Answer (score 1):

It should take less than 10 minutes to flash an image to a new SD Card. (Tools that verify the image after writing take a little longer.) Even my large backup images take just over 10 minutes.

If it takes longer than this the SD Card is worn out (or faulty).

Comment: Thanks for that Milliways.Have a nice day.